# Javascript redirect - New Window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to create a re-direct using Javascript from inside a blank iframe that will direct to a URL inside a new window or tab.

More specifically, I'm trying to make a Facebook tab point to my company's webpage rather than load the page inside the tab's iframe which is not the same width as our web page.

Here is the redirect script I already have but it doesn't open the URL in a new window.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--Redirect to 75th page
var time = null
function move() {
window.location = 'http://philmontscoutranch.org/Camping/75.aspx'
}
timer=setTimeout('move()',0000)
//-->
</script>
```

---

Ok - This snippet will open a new window when the page loads but Chrome's pop-up blocker blocked it. I didn't think about this until now. Maybe I could have it load in a light window?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--Redirect to 75th page
var time = null
function open_win()
{
window.open("http://philmontscoutranch.org/Camping/75.aspx", "_blank");
}

timer=setTimeout('open_win()',0000)
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: Did you try window.open instead of window.location? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Will not chrome block any try to call `window.open` and assignments to `window.location` not triggered by user events?

Answer (score 9):

Here you go: [Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zachrip/hqKQg/1)

```
function opennewtab(url){
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function open_win()
{
window.open("http://philmontscoutranch.org/Camping/75.aspx", "_blank");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="open_win()">
</body>
</html>
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: Thanks, this will open a new tab when the button is clicked but is there a way to make the new tab open as soon as the iframe finishes loading and not requiring the visitor to click a button?

Comment: Just add the function to the `onload` event of your body tag : `<body onload="open_win()">`